# iterative solution python (finding the last and second last iterative values)

Tags: python, iteration

I am total beginner in programming and have to write a short code in python. Its about finding an iterative solution for a variable when the difference between the successive iterations is no more than 0.0001.

I thought of using an infinite while loop but how can I check what are the values obtained after second last and last iteration so that I could specify the break condition.

Please can someone explain how to do that?

Here is the code I've written

```
Icl=0.5
tc= 25 
def kelvin(tc):
    tk = tc +273.15
    return tk

#calculate the initial value for tcl

tcl=kelvin(tc)+(35.5-tc)/(3.5*Icl+0.1)

#calculate the final value of tcl when the difference between the successive values of tcl <0.0001

while true:
    tcl=35.7-0.028*(M-Icl)*(3.96e-8*fcl((tcl+273.15)**4-(tr+273.15)**4+fcl*hc*(tcl-ta))

    if .... #here I am not sure how to break the loop when above mentioned condition is met
```

Comment: The way you've described the problem is really confusing, but if you need to store your results from each iteration, just append them to a list, or just maintain a variable for the previous iteration. Also, it will be difficult to help without seeing some code.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far...

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys. I have added the code in my post. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you only store `tcl` where you need to store `tcl` and `previous_tcl`. At the minimum, you can modify your code this way:

```
cl=0.5 tc= 25 def kelvin(tc): tk = tc +273.15 return tk

#calculate the initial values for tcl and tcl_previous
tcl_previous = kelvin(tc)+(35.5-tc)/(3.5*Icl+0.1)
tcl = 35.7-0.028*(M-Icl)*(3.96e-8*fcl((tcl_previous+273.15)**4-(tr+273.15)**4+fclhc(tcl_previous-ta))

#calculate the final value of tcl when the difference between the successive values of tcl <0.0001

while math.abs(tcl-tcl_previous)>0.0001:
    tcl_previous = tcl
    tcl = 35.7-0.028*(M-Icl)*(3.96e-8*fcl((tcl_previous +273.15)**4-(tr+273.15)**4+fclhc(tcl_previous -ta))
```

Note that this is not the cleanner way to write it because the line that calculates `tcl` from `tcl_previous` is duplicated. You should encapsulate it in a function.